# Как много функций собрать в одну

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Попробую сформулировать свой вопрос правильно.
К примеру у меня есть...

функция номер1
   она выводит дату и время

функция номер2
   меняет цвет у блока

функция номер3
   меняет положение блока

итд...

Просто я обратил внимание у многих javascript. jquery плагинов именно так сделано, когда их ставишь ты сам типа как в конфиге отмечаешь что тебе нужно..
Вот как пример вызов одного из плагинов

```js
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
  scrollingSpeed: 500,
  easing: 'linear',
  loopTop: true,
  loopBottom: true,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  sectionSelector: '.screen',
  navigation: {
   'position': 'navigation',
   'tooltips': ['']
  }
 });
});
```

Как это правильно называется? и как так делают? что можно по этой теме изучить?
Спасибо.

Comment: дак это и есть конфиг, а не "как в конфиге". объект настроек же передается как параметр

Comment: А можно где то  про это более подробно почитать ?

Comment: возьмите плагин попроще (покороче) какой  да изучите исходный код